# Installing Ubuntu phone

Tags: ubuntu-touch, system-installation

I have a HTC One runing android 4.4. I was wondering if ubuntu phone works for my phone. I read very quick the how to guide on the web page but I'm not sure about doing it. Has anyone done? How does it work?

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu Phone is only available on the Galaxy Nexus and the Nexus 4, Nexus 7 and Nexus 10 officially, after you could use this tutorial to install it, I have an Nexus 5, I didn't try it so I won't be responsible on what could happen with your device. Good luck